Fermi-Dirac integrals of different orders
Which physical quantities are related to the Fermi-Dirac integrals of different orders?
In Fermi-Dirac integral, written like this:
$$F_\xi(\eta_c) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\xi+1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\xi}}{1+\exp(x-\eta_c)} \mathrm{d}x \ ,$$
$F_{1/2}(\eta_c)$ is related to carrier density and $F_{3/2}(\eta_c)$ is related to carrier mean energy. So, if $\xi = -3/2, -1, -1/2, 0, 1$, which physical quantities are related to those orders of Fermi-Dirac integrals?
This question arises from an article I was reading, where the author wrote carrier electrical conductivity $\sigma_c$, carrier thermal conductivity $\kappa_c$ like the following:
$$\sigma_c = qN_c\mu_c^0\frac{F_0(\eta_c)}{F_{1/2}(\eta_c)}$$
$$\kappa_c = k^2\sigma_c\frac{T_e}{q^2}\left[6F_2(\eta_c)F_0(\eta_c)-\frac{4F_1(\eta_c)^2}{F_0(\eta_c)^2}\right].$$
I know that electrical conductivity $\sigma_c$ can be written as $\sigma_c = qN_c\mu_c^0$. But I don't know what is the meaning of $\dfrac{F_0(\eta_c)}{F_{1/2}(\eta_c)}$. In this article, there is another ratio of Fermi-Dirac integrals in parameters' expression, like $\dfrac{F_{1/2}(\eta_c)}{F_{-1/2}(\eta_c)}$.
I also want to know whether the ratio of different orders of Fermi-Dirac integrals has a special physical meaning.
The article's title: "Kinetics of high-density plasmas generated in Si by 1.06 and 0.53-pm picosecond laser pulses".

One usually already knows what it is they are looking for and derive the appropriate relations between them and the Fermi-Dirac integrals. The opposite direction is not often useful.

Thanks for your comment. If possible, could you provide me with some information about physical quantities related to the Fermi-Dirac integrals of different orders? I would greatly appreciate it.

It is not only energy or density. The order wil changing depending if you take 1D, 2D, or a 3D system. Here you have a 3D system. For a 2D system the power should be one since  density of states does not depend on the energy, and for 1D it is proportional to $E^{-1/2}$ (all is related to a parabolic dispersion relation)

check this link, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states

If there is another dispersion in a semiconductor, the power will be different

Thank you Polovodov. Your comments are really helpful. I will read this wikipedia to get knowledge about density of states. Thank you again.
